# how to use Boost Asio in MFC Dialog based application?

Tags: c++, boost, mfc

I made a MFC dialog based application.
I need to handle the Http Server's request and response, 
thus I chose the Boost(boost_1_56_0) Asio example(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html) to use in mfc dialog.

After building the MFC project, i ran the application.
The result of running it was that the dialog window was not shown but the process was still running.

How can i solve the this problem.

follow the code fragment of it

```
    CTestDlg::CTestDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CTestDlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_static_message(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    // server start 
    http::server::server s("localhost", "12345", ".");
    s.run();
}
```

Comment: If `s.run()` does not return until the server has stopped, you would be better off implementing the server in a seperate worker thread.

Comment: thank you for your comments. i did coded the console app for boost and draw the dialog for user input and results